# EF Core, object not able to reference other objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a tree like structure. This tree has `Nodes`. Every object in my project has the ability to link to one of these nodes. However when I query using LINQ for an object it is unable to return that referenced nodes data.

```
public async Task<NodeModel> FindByID(string pID, CancellationToken pCancellationToken)
{
    pCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    return await Context.Nodes.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == pID);
}
```

Above is how I query the context for a single object based on `ID`. The photo below shows that its returning `null`.

[image]

For some Clarity.  B is a child of A.
When I query the list like so

```
mContext.Nodes.ToList();
```

I the query is able to link the nodes?

What is going on here?

[image]

Comment: _"What is going on here?!?!"_ - magic. The context tracks all entities, and attaches those if it's seen them. If you query one entity, it won't have seen other entities. But that's not the question you want answered. The answer to that question is to use `Include()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because you have lazily loaded navigation properties.

Try altering your query like this

```
public async Task<NodeModel> FindByID(string pID, CancellationToken pCancellationToken)
{
        pCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        return await Context.Nodes.Include(m => m.Node).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == pID);

}
```

The reason is works when you query all of the records is that Entity Framework is smart enough to know that it already has that entity loaded. Because you're querying the full data set in that case, the nodes are already loaded.

Comment: Yes this worked, I attempted this before but i was using this code.
return await Context.Nodes.Include(m => m.Nodes).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == pID);

and it obviously didn't work. Stupid me, gave up on .Include to quick.

Comment: Great. As an aside, you can if you want to edit the Entity class and make your property virtual (ie. public virtual NodeModel Node {get; set;}). If you do that, the first time you try and access the Node property EF will do a round trip to the DB to get it for you. It's often not the best way to work as it might trigger multiple calls to the DB, but it's worth knowing about.